# Difference between amiko and geamikoj

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I learned that amiko and geamikoj means friend, and am wonder how they are differently used.

My initial guess is 'geamikoj' means mutual relationship so it is not used as a singular form as 'geamiko'

So...

```
Li estas mia amiko

Ili estas mia amikoj

Ili estas geamikoj
```

all make sense, but

```
Li estas mia geamiko
```

does not make sense.

Is my guess correct?

Comment: Welcome to learning Esperanto! I would like to recommend as a good beginner's course the course [_La teorio Nakamura_](https://lernu.net/kurso/nakamura) at a site called Lernu, which has other material too. The course is available in several languages.

Comment: Before asking it is a recommend practice to search here whether the same or a related question has been asked before. For instance just two months ago there was this question [_Can the prefix ge- only appear in plural nouns (with -oj) and without -in-?_](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/6597/can-the-prefix-ge-only-appear-in-plural-nouns-with-oj-and-without-in) which takes up the _amikoj/geamikoj_ issue Neil mentions.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix *ge-* is added to a word to mean it contains a mix of genders. So for example *patro* is a father, *patrino* is a mother and *gepatroj* is a group of mothers and fathers (or most likely one mother and one father).

So *amiko* means *friend*, and *geamikoj* is a group of friends with different genders.

*Geamiko* is generally not used in singular form because in traditional Esperanto that would mean a single person that is somehow related to multiple genders, which is an unusual thing to say.

*Amiko* is a bit of a special case because there is disagreement over whether it is a gender-neutral word. Some sources (such as [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/o-vortoj/seksa_signifo.html#i-b36)) argue that *amiko* is neutral meaning that the *ge-* prefix is redundant and *amikoj* alone could be a mix of men and women. On the other hand [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#amiko_kdc) explicitly says that an *amiko* is a man so you would need to say *amikino* for a female friend and *geamikoj* for a group of friends of mixed gender.